# If summation of Projections on Vector Space over complex number is Identity then their pairwise product is Zero operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation, projection, projection-matrices

> Let $F$ be a subﬁeld of the complex numbers (or, a ﬁeld of characteristic zero). Let $V$ be a ﬁnite-dimensional vector space over $F$. Suppose that $E_1,\dots,E_k$ are projections of $V$ and that $E_1+\dots+E_k=I$. Prove that $E_iE_j=0$ for $i\ne j$. (Hint: Use the trace function and ask yourself what the trace of a projection is.

This is Exercise 10 from Section 6.6 (Direct-Sum Decompositions) in Hoffman, Kunze: *Linear algebra*.

**I have following solution**
[image]

Please help in understanding: If $W_{ij}$ is the range of $E_iE_j$. Then (a) how $tr(E_iE_j)=\dim(W_{ij})$ and (b) if $\dim(W_{ij})=0$ then how $E_iE_j=0$ for $i\ne j$?

Comment: There are other methods to do this problem but I want to understand the solution through this method.

Comment: (b) is immediate: if the range of a linear transformation is zero, then it is the zero map.

Comment: @Berci Thanks. I got your point. Do you have any suggestion for (a)?

Comment: (a) would follow if we knew that $E_iE_j$ is also a projection. But proving this might not be easier than finding another way to prove the claim.

Comment: In the same basis which diagonalizes $E$, what is the matrix of $E_iE_j$? In the same way that $\dim  W_i = \mbox{tr } E_i$, you should get the analogous result for $E_iE_j$.

Comment: @астон Okay in the basis which diagonalizes E's, the multiple of two diagonal matrices with entries 0's and 1's is again a diagonal matrix with entries 0's and 1's so product of two projection is again a projection and for any projection operator P, tr(P)=dim of its range. \\ But I think we should also use the concept of simultaneous diagonalizability on E's. And yes I got your point Thankyou again.

Comment: you are  welcome! Can I close the question by writing an answer as I did for the other question?

Comment: Yeah, That would be good.

Answer (score 1):

The comment was wrong!

Yes, we do require simultaneous diagonalizability, which then takes some time to prove, so as Berci says, this method is more time taking than another proof which I will show.

For this, we need to show that the projections commute i.e. $E_iE_k = E_kE_i$. For this, write $\sum E_j = I$. Therefore, $\sum_{j \neq i} E_j = I-E_i$. From here, we get $\sum_{j \neq i} E_iE_jE_i =E_i(1-E_i)E_i=0$. Now, note that $E_iE_jE_i = (E_iE_j)(E_iE_j)^H$ since $E_i,E_j$  are projections, so we get $\sum_{j \neq i} (E_iE_j)(E_iE_j)^H = 0$.

(Where $\cdot^H$  denotes the conjugate transpose, or the Hermitian transpose).

From this, clearly $E_iE_j = 0$ for each $i,j$, see this yourself.

This is the shortest method to show that $E_i,E_j$ commute, but it also shows the products are zero, as desired. I think you should go with this proof itself.

Comment: Given that this is in a complex vector space, you should use the conjugate transpose instead of the transpose.

Comment: True, thank you for that.